# Datastore disk usage is too high

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

When trying to deploy my code to UAT, the Jenkins job makes a copy of the Jar in the arti-factory before actually deploying the JAR to the server. When the Jenkins hit the artifactory, it is throwing "Datastore disk usage is too high. Contact your Artifactory administrator to add additional storage space or change the disk quota limits. Status code: 413"

Answer (score 0):

This error is as clear as it gets - you do not have enough storage on the disk that hosts Artifactory's filestore. You should increase the storage on your server and this will solve this issue.